# Youtube thumbnail + playicon for links

Tags: html, facebook, youtube

Recently I've on Facebook seen links to external sites that have a Youtube embed, that shows a huge videothumbnail on the timeline + a Youtube-play icon.

Here's a screenshot: 
[image]

I've tried to do some research and also done some tests to see if it was simply Facebook who did this, but I've not been able to find the right solution.

Does anyone of you know?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style>
   .oVideo {
      width: 300px;
      height: 150px;
      background-color: #f00;
      position: relative;
   }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="oVideo">
   <!-- INSERT PREVIEW AND PLAY IMAGE HERE WITH AN ABSOLUTE POSITION -->
</div>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.oVideo').click(function () {
         var video = '<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/6TgyvSQlJtI?wmode=transparent&enablejsapi=1&rel=0&autohide=1&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="video"></iframe>';
         $('.oVideo').html(video);
         // REMOVE THE PREVIEW AND PLAY IMAGE ELEMENTS HERE
      });
   });
</script>
```

and then just add the preview-image and the play button image in the '.oVideo' element and hide them when clicked on the overlay.

Comment: But its on Facebook I want this image. Not on my own page